# Highcharts - how can a chart with multi pies change container height automatic?

Tags: highcharts

```
[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpfBs/22/)
```

2 problem:

1. I create a charts with multi pies, but some of pies was hidden. If I change the height of container, every one of the pie get bigger, but still some pies was hidden.
2. There are different name of each pie,so how can I display the name in pie?

Comment: You need to modify your positin parameters, I mean center and Y, because there are place pie chart in coordination which cause hide pie chart partly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to set size for chart and pies.

```
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',            
type: 'pie',
height:800     //height for chart
}
```

size in series set total size for pie,innerSize set inner blank size for pie.

But what about the 2nd question? How can set to display name for every pie?

Answer (score 0):

For pie labels, use chart labels, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/YDdna/

Code for all: position + inner size + labels:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    labels: {
        items: [{
            html: '1st title',
            style: {
                left: '220px',
                top: '90px'
            }
        }, {
            html: '2nd title',
            style: {
                left: '220px',
                top: '310px'
            }
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        center: [220, 80],
        size: 150,
        innerSize: 90,
        data: [3, 4, 3]
    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        center: [220, 300],
        size: 150,
        innerSize: 90,
        data: [3, 4, 3]
    }]
});
```